# Which allocator are available in STLPORT, and how to use them

Tags: c++, stl, allocator, stlport

We're using STLPORT and we'd like to change stlport's default allocator:
instead of vector<int>, we'd like to try vector<int, otherallocator>

Which alternative allocator are available in stlport, and what are their features?
How do I use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.stlport.org/doc/configure.html) for switching the default allocator. I think you'll find the available allocator implementations are under `include/stlport/stl/` in your installation.
That said, it's a standard [interface](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/alloc.html) and you can [implement your own](http://www.ddj.com/article/printableArticle.jhtml;jsessionid=UVIHN30KXFX0RQE1GHPSKH4ATMY32JVN?articleID=184403759&dept_url=/cpp/).